# Neural Network Error, Can anyone help me?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I was watching the YouTube video by Neural Nine about how to create an intelligent chatbot using neural networks (link to the video = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lwddP0KUEg). I followed it step by step. Everything worked fine until I tried to execute the training.py document.

The following code:

```
import random
import json
import pickle
from tabnanny import verbose
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer     # used for the word stem (ex. work, work-ed, work-ing)

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v1 import SGD

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['!', '?', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)  # tokenize splits the sentence into individual words (ex. "I like Python" = "I", "like", "PYthon")
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]    #makes the words individual
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(words, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

# -->we need to represent the words as NUMERICAL NUMBERS<--
training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words: 
        bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

#   NEURAL NETWORK MODEL
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbot_model.model')
print("Done")
```

gave me the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Winrob-Studios\Chatbot\AI\Neural Network\training.py", line 68, in <module>
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 567, in compile    
    self._validate_compile(optimizer, metrics, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2635, in _validate_compile
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: ('`tf.compat.v1.keras` Optimizer (', <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v1.SGD object at 0x000002DD585C6680>, ') is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use a `tf.keras` Optimizer instead, or disable eager execution.')
```

Any ideas? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. You should demonstrate your attempt to understand the error message, and ask a specific, directed question about whatever it is you can't figure out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way. Add this under the import section:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

You could find the fix yourself by inspecting your error log:

```
Use a `tf.keras` Optimizer instead, or disable eager execution.
```

And look at google to `disable eager execution`, which `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` does.